# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1836 Shaw Lane Apt. 733\nGracetown, PW 83118-5264'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, linear-regression

```
python-3
```

How Should I solve This-
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1836 Shaw Lane Apt. 733\nGracetown, PW 83118-5264'

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5000 entries, 0 to 4999
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column                        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                        --------------  -----  
 0   Avg. Area Income              5000 non-null   float64
 1   Avg. Area House Age           5000 non-null   float64
 2   Avg. Area Number of Rooms     5000 non-null   float64
 3   Avg. Area Number of Bedrooms  5000 non-null   float64
 4   Area Population               5000 non-null   float64
 5   Price                         5000 non-null   float64
 6   Address                       5000 non-null   object 
dtypes: float64(6), object(1)
memory usage: 273.6+ KB
```

===========================

```
feature = df[['Avg_Area_Income', 'Avg_Area_House_Age', 'Avg_Area_Number_of_Rooms',
            'Avg_Area_Number_of_Bedrooms', 'Area_Population','Price', 'Address']]

target = df[['Price']]

==========
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(feature,target, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)

========
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
```

Comment: Very confused why you're including `'Address'` in `feature`.

Comment: if I drop "Address" it's still doesn't work sir

Comment: If you drop address, what error do you get?

Comment: @CHaworth same Error sir

Comment: Could you please print some lines of your data frame?

Comment: thank you so much, sir,
I was trying for a long by myself but I cant then I put my question here then in a Second I found my answer by talking with you guys.
so what I was doing actually dropped that "Address" column after Splitting that's why it's showed an error. now when I drop before Splitting now all good.
actually, I am so sorry sir for brother you for this silly matter. again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You added ["price", "address"] in your **X** variable. Remember, you are predicting for **df["Price"]**, which is your **y** variable, so you can't have it included in as a feature or X variable.

df["Address"] is a string with data that doesn't contribute to your model's accuracy. So you can also remove that.

X = df[['Avg. Area Income', 'Avg. Area House Age', 'Avg. Area Number of Rooms',
'Avg. Area Number of Bedrooms', 'Area Population', **'Price', 'Address'**]]

Should be:

X = df[['Avg. Area Income', 'Avg. Area House Age', 'Avg. Area Number of Rooms',
'Avg. Area Number of Bedrooms', 'Area Population']]

Answer (score 0):

feature= df[['Avg. Area Income', 'Avg. Area House Age', 'Avg. Area Number of Rooms', 'Avg. Area Number of Bedrooms', 'Area Population']]

target = df[['Price']]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).